# Clarification for exporting a LibGDX game as an applet

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, libgdx

I'm trying to follow the [guide](http://www.thesecretpie.com/2011/05/being-like-minecraft-or-how-to-run-your.html) to export my project as a Java applet.

My project, as seen in Eclipse, has three directories:

```
Game
Game-Android
Game-Desktop
```

They were created using the UI Setup tool. The guide at http://www.thesecretpie.com/2011/05/being-like-minecraft-or-how-to-run-your.html is confusing and I don't understand these points:

> Next step: add a new file called HelloWorldApplet.java (in the same
>   directory as other source files).

"The same directory as other source files". Well, I have three directories and they all have a source folder. In which of these three am I supposed to put this file? I tried placing it in `Game`, but Eclipse is unable to resolve `com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplet`. If I put it in `Game-Desktop` it seems to be OK, but I'm not sure.

> Create a directory called applet in your project dir.

Again, in which of my three directories?

> Just export the whole project as jar in Eclipse

I can export a JAR for `Game`, `Game-Android`, or `Game-Desktop`. Which of these?

---

Related:

I happen to be using the JRuby JAR in my game to run some ruby scripting logic. Do I have to do something specific about it?

Answer (score 1):

That blog is little old.  For example, the JOGL backend is gone from recent version of Libgdx (so you don't need to worry about switching to the LWJGL backend).  Also, the current LWJGL bundled into Libgdx is 2.9.0 (hopefully that doesn't change too much, though).

I believe the instructions are effectively packing up the "desktop" build of your app into an Applet (as the desktop is the only build that use the LWJGL backend), so assume `Game-Desktop` is the "same directory" that its talking about.

Thus, you should export the .JAR from your Desktop project.

On a related note, there is another way to run your game on the web, using the GWT backend.  Check out the [Setup & Running page](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-setup%2C-running-%26-debugging) (where its called "HTML5").  There are a bunch of caveats on using the GWT backend (not all Libgdx APIs work over there).  (Hmm... I doubt this will work with the JRuby JAR, so probably not worth spending too much time on that.)